# psycopg2 fails to install on centOS

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to install psycopg2 on centOS.

I did

```
yum install postgresql-libs python-devel
yum install postgresql-devel
yum install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

When I do

```
pip install psycopg2
```

I get

```
gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/green.o 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/pqpath.o 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/utils.o 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/connection_int.o 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/connection_type.o 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/cursor_int.o 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/cursor_type.o 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/error_type.o 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/lobject_int.o 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/lobject_type.o 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/notify_type.o 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/xid_type.o 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/typecast.o -L/usr/lib64 -lpq -o
build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
/usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o: 
relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against `lobjectType' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Failed building wheel for psycopg2
Failed to build psycopg2
```

Even if I download psycopg2 from http://initd.org/psycopg/tarballs/PSYCOPG-2-6/psycopg2-2.6.tar.gz
 and do `python setup.py install`, I get the same error.

what's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Install additional `libs`:

```
sudo yum install python-devel postgresql-devel postgresql-libs gcc
```

and in virtualenv export path to postgres:

```
export PATH=/path/to/compiled/postgresql/bin:"$PATH"
```

in most cases it is (note you have to set correct version in path, e.g. for PostgreSQL 9.5 it will be psql-9.5 and so on):

```
export PATH=/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin:"$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue fixed in release 2.3.1 
Install the version 2.3.1: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psycopg2/2.3.1

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the correct version of python-devel. If you are using python3 then you will need the right version of python3 devel.

First make sure you have postgresql-devel installed:

`yum install postgresql-devel`

To make sure you have the correct version do a search like following:

`yum search devel  | grep python`

Choose the write python version devel package and install it. For python3 it was

`yum install python3-devel.x86_64`

Finally you can install psycopg2 using pip:

`pip install psycopg2`

Answer (score 0):

Check this issue on github even answer is there.

https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/305